# Freeing allocated memory: am I missing something?

Tags: c, memory-management

If this question should be on stackoverflow instead, please point it out. I'll put it up there.

```
 struct {
      FILE * fd;
      hdr_t file_header;
      body_t file_body;
 } fileinfo;
```

The above is an approximate recreation of a structure that I have in my code. There is a separate function we use for thread cleanup. A pointer to the above structure is a parameter to this function.

```
 void cleanup(void * args) 
 {
      struct fileinfo *file_ptr = (struct fileinfo *) args;

      if(file_ptr->fd > 0)
      {
           fclose(file_ptr->fd);
      }
      free(file_ptr);
  }
```

Does the free() - as called above - actually free all the memory allocated to file_ptr? Should there not be a free for the hdr_t and body_t as well?

Comment: You must not call `free` on the `hdr_t` or `body_t` fields - they are part of the structure and were not allocated individually. The `FILE` pointer should be compared with `...fd != 0` not `>`.  If it is a `FILE` obtained with `fopen`, then you need to call `fclose`, not `close` and it should be named something other than `fd` (which is normally used for things opened with `open`), eg call it `file`. You  do not need to call `free` on the file pointer (`fclose` will do what is required).  You might need to free the `fileinfo` struct itself, if it was allocate dynamically, but not in `cleanup`

Comment: Sorry, the free/close issues were typos. I've corrected them in the question.

Comment: your if statement has an unbalanced number of brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic logic is that you only free dynamically allocated resources. Those that were created with malloc.

Hdr_t and body_t are automatically allocated and must therefore not be freed.

The most important point is that you might under no circumstances free a pointer without checking if it is not pointing to 0.

This following fragment will core:

```
void * ptr = 0;
free (ptr);
```

Therefore always do something like this:

```
if (ptr != 0)
    free(ptr)
```

Comment: i did a bit of a SO research and a similar question has been posted before. It might explain it even better. [freeing ptr to ptr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647350/freeing-struct-with-pointer-and-non-pointer-variables)

Comment: new does not apply to `C` malloc/free is used for dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: The bit about checking for NULL before freeing is wrong. The standard library already does this (the standard was amended). It was true about 10 years ago no longer so. But you must check for NULL before looking at the members.

Comment: I know what you mean by `Hdr_t and body_t are statically`. But `statically` is the wrong description and has specific meaning within the context of the language. I don't have a C standard handy so I forget the actual term.

Comment: I agree on the NULL condition. This applies to 99 strict and older C++ standards. Yet I've worked on environments where this still holds. The correct term for allocation is automatic.